# Count records after where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: `Catalog`, `Upload` and `Product`. A product belongs to a catalog, and an upload belongs to a product.

I need to count the number of uploads for all the products of a given catalog.

This is the way I've been doing it so far, which is incredibly slow for a large amount of uploads or products:

```
@products = Product.where(catalog_id: 123)
@uploads_count = Upload.where(product_id: @products.pluck(:id)).count
```

I'd like to avoid loading all the products just for a count.
Should I use raw SQL or is there a better way to do this with ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
Upload.joins(:product).where(products: { catalog_id: 123 }).count
```

Using `joins` creates an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables, allowing you to query the products table as above.

Note the singular and plural uses of `product` - the joins should reflect the association (the `upload` belongs to *one* `product`), while the where clause *always* uses the table name, typically pluralised.

The SQL will look similar to:

```
SELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads" 
INNER JOIN "products" 
ON "products"."id" = "uploads"."product_id" 
WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 123
```

If you need to have more information on the catalog you can also include this, something like the following:

```
Upload.joins(product: :catalog).where(products: { catalogs: { whatever: 'you want to query' } }).count
```

Bear in mind, using `joins` is just for a query such as this. If you need to access attributes of the product or catalog, you should use another approach, such as `includes`, to preload the data and avoid N + 1 queries. There's a good read [here](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid selecting records is to use sub-query. This can be done the following way:

```
query = User.where(id: 1..100)
User.where(id: query.select(:id)).count
# [DEBUG]  (10.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" BETWEEN $1 AND $2))  [["id", 1], ["id", 100]]
# => 33
```

So, `User.where(id: 1..100)` prepares a query, that can be used as a sub-select. `.select(:field)` tells what field you are interested in.
Though for a basic count, SRack provides a good answer.